# Rails/FullCalendar/JQuery Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, fullcalendar

I'm working on trying to integrate a calendar into my RoR web application using FullCalendar.

I've imported jQuery, Moment, and FullCalendar. Basically, what i'm trying to do is make a pop up appear that lets the user add an event to the calendar whenever they click on a date.

I followed this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NiTLuPqvt58&t=349s

Here are the errors i'm getting:

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8BFO.png)

Using 'puts' and 'console.log' i've followed my route down to the Events controller new method. I'm not sure what i'm supposed to be rendering here. Also, date_range_picker could be a jQuery function or something from FullCalendar not sure.

Here's code:

**full_calendar.js**

```
    var intialize_calendar;
initialize_calendar = function() {
  $('.calendar').each(function() {
    var calendar = $(this);
    calendar.fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next,today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay'
    },
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true,

    select: function(start, end) {
      $.getScript("/events/new", function() {

        $("#event_date_range").val(moment(start).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm") + ' - ' + moment(end).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm"));
        date_range_picker();
        $(".start_hidden").val(moment(start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"));
        $(".end_hidden").val(moment(start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"));

      })
      calendar.fullCalendar("unselect");
    }
  });
});
}

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', initialize_calendar)
```

**events_controller.rb**

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @event.Event.new
  end
end
```

**new.js.erb**

```
$('#remote_container').html('<%= j render ("new") %>');
$('#new_event').modal('show');
```

Comment: first thing: you include `require fullcalendar` but your filname is full_calendar.js ?

Comment: You should check the response of the ajax call. What is the return of /events/new . The error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : at DOMEval` I see often, when the parsing of JSON fails. Please tell us what the network tab of your inspector says.

Comment: So, 'full_calender.js' is the file i'm using that writes the above javascript. 'fullcalender.js' is the file that was imported with the FullCalendar gem. After tinkering with it for a while I did get rid of that error, and now i'm getting 'VM874:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <' lol

Comment: I edited this question to be more descriptive.